# Itext count number of signed signature fields

Tags: java, itext

I need to get the number of signed fields in a pdf document . Right now I'm doing this this way:

```
ServletContext app = getServletContext();
String path = app.getRealPath("/CompesationReportsPdfDocuments/mySignedPdf.pdf");
File thePdf = new File(path);
int numberOfSignedFields=0;
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
AcroFields fields = reader .getAcroFields();
numberOfSignedFields=fields.getSignatureNames().size();
reader .close();
```

And when I do

```
System.out.printline("Number of signed fields :"+numberOfSignedFields);
```

I get

```
Number of signed fields :0
```

Comment: `fields.getSignatureNames().size()` should do the job all right. As it does not work, can you provide your sample document for reproducing the issue? (BTW, we are talking about signature fields with digital signatures, don't we? And not this mere scribbling on some touch pad stored as some graphic...)

Comment: Yes we are , that does the job ! But what happens now is that when I download previously uploaded and signed pdf it is shown as invalid by adobe reader although it is fine on local server - it opens ok , somewhere in my download process in my servlet I am making an error , I posted a new question on that...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Hope it'll help you out:

```
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader("MYPDF.pdf");

int position = reader.getAcroFields().getSignatureNames().size();
```

Comment: This essentially *is* what the op did himself.